# Spam mail from my yahoo mail

Tags: email, spam, keyloggers, yahoo

Couple of days back spam mail(screenshot link) was sent to all my contacts from my yahoo account, and in my account activity page there is a yahoo partner logged in, from Peru (screenshot link) during that time.

I have reset my PW, security question, checked alternate email address and removed 3 links (e.g. tripit.com) from website connections, which I don't remember adding.

Can someone please confirm that this mail was sent by my website connections, and not sent by a virus or key logger which is stealing my password.

http://wikisend.com/download/349080/spam mail.png
http://wikisend.com/download/403024/activity log.png

Thanks,
kiran

Comment: I believe this is out of the scope of this site.  Also, why are the screenshots on Wikisend and not embedded here?

Answer (score 2):

Lately, it has been very common for e-mails to be spoofed as if they are from someone on your contact list or on your Facebook friends.  These often don't require actually compromising the account and are instead simply faked and sent.  The best way to determine if this is the case is to look at the header of one of the e-mails and see if it actually resolves from a genuine Yahoo mail server or not.  If not, you have nothing to worry about.

If it does, then I'm not sure there is a good way to tell what the origin of the message is unless there is some info in the activity log or in the header of the message to indicate how it was sent.  Your best bet would be to contact Yahoo and ask them for assistance.